# How can i find the core dumped error in the function

Tags: c

I am trying to do a roulette in C with a custom graphic library, however when i click on one button that call the Mise() function i get a core dumped error :
segmentation error (core dumped)

The function Mise() look like this

```
int Mise(int ChoixChiffre[37], int ChoixCouleur, int ChoixDouzaine[3], int ChoixParite, int ChoixPlage, int MiseChiffre[37], int MiseCouleur, int MiseDouzaine[3], int MiseParite, int MisePlage, int ArgentJoueur, int resultatRoulette) 

{
    int gainTotal = 0; // Réinitialisation du gain total

    int Couleur = getCouleur(resultatRoulette); //Get the color of the number resultatRoulette

    for(int i = 1; i<37; i++) {
        if(ChoixChiffre[i] == resultatRoulette)
        {
            ArgentJoueur = ArgentJoueur + MiseChiffre[i] * 36;
        }
    }

    if(ChoixCouleur == Couleur) {
        ArgentJoueur = ArgentJoueur + MiseCouleur * 2;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i<3;i++) {
        if(ChoixDouzaine[i] == CheckDouzaine(resultatRoulette))
        {
            ArgentJoueur = ArgentJoueur + MiseDouzaine[i] * 3;
        }
    }

    if((ChoixParite  == 1 && resultatRoulette / 2 == 0) ||( ChoixParite == 0 && resultatRoulette !=0)) {
        ArgentJoueur = ArgentJoueur + MiseParite * 2;
    }

    if(ChoixPlage == CheckPlage(resultatRoulette)) {
        ArgentJoueur = ArgentJoueur + MisePlage * 2;
    }
    return ArgentJoueur;
}
```

ChoixChiffre[37] allow you to bet on one number : if i want to bet on the fifth number then i just have to put ChoixChiffre[5] to 1
MiseChiffre[37] work the same except the array hold the bet you did
ChoixDouzaine and MiseDouzaine works the same but with only 3 numbers

The place where i call the function look like this :

```
if(abscisseSouris() >= 534 && abscisseSouris() <= 641 && ordonneeSouris() <= 583 && ordonneeSouris() >= 533)
            {
        int resultatRoulette = lancerRoulette();                

        ArgentJoueur = Mise(ChoixChiffre[37],ChoixCouleur,  ChoixDouzaine[3], ChoixParite,  ChoixPlage,  MiseChiffre[37],  MiseCouleur, MiseDouzaine[3],  MiseParite,  MisePlage, ArgentJoueur, resultatRoulette);

        ChoixCouleur = 0;
        ChoixParite = 0;
        ChoixPlage = 0;
        MiseCouleur = 0;
        MiseParite =0;
        MisePlage = 0;
        printf("Test");

        for(int i = 1; i<37;i++) {
            MiseChiffre[i] = 0;
            ChoixChiffre[i] = 0;
        }

        for(int i = 1; i<3;i++) {
            MiseDouzaine[i] = 0;
            ChoixDouzaine[i] = 0;
        }       

        MiseDouzaine[3] = 0;
        ChoixDouzaine[3] = 0;

        cercle(blancx[resultatRoulette], blancy[resultatRoulette], 20);
}
```

Here's the code of getCouleur()

```
int getCouleur(int nombre) //0 si Vert, 1 si Rouge, 2 si Noir
{
    int noir[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 29, 31, 33, 35};

    for (int i = 1; i < 18; i++) {
        if (nombre == noir[i]) {
            return 2;
        }
        if (nombre == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I tried changing the numbers in the for and corrected some bugs but i can't find from where the core dumped could come from

Comment: When you pass an array to a function you just use its name, not the dimension. So `ArgentJoueur = Mise(ChoixChiffre[37],...` is incorrect and `ArgentJoueur = Mise(ChoixChiffre,...` is correct. More importantly, `ChoixChiffre[37]` is a single integer and it is out of range for the array since the valid indices are 0 to 36 for a 37 element array. If you are not seeing several compiler warnings for this code you should adjust your settings until you do and you must pay attention to them.

Comment: Thanks ! That litteraly solved everything